# Using filter to calculate mean gives wrong value

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

I have a panel data set and I am trying to calculate the mean value for different groups. I use the following function:

```
mean(x = filter(panel, dv_id== 1 )$price, y = filter(panel, dvv_id== 1)$price)
```

However, when I use this function:

```
panel %>%
    group_by(dv_id, dvv_id) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(price, na.rm=TRUE))
```

I do get a different mean value for the group combination I am looking for.

Comment: plz share your data with `dput`

Comment: @OmarAbdEl-Naser How can I copy the data? The df is too large to fully select in the console.

Comment: filter for only c(1) group in both of them then `dput`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't give you wrong values but we are using the function incorrectly. Since you haven't shared a reproducible example, let's try to use `mtcars` dataset to understand.

```
library(dplyr)
#Same as your attempt 
mean(x = filter(mtcars, am == 1 )$mpg, y = filter(mtcars, vs == 1)$mpg) #gives
#[1] 24.39231
```

Now let's select `vs == 0`

```
mean(x = filter(mtcars, am == 1 )$mpg, y = filter(mtcars, vs == 0)$mpg)
#[1] 24.39231
```

The answer is still the same, that's strange. Now let's add a very big number

```
mean(x = filter(mtcars, am == 1 )$mpg, y = 100000)
#[1] 24.39231
```

The answer is still the same which means that irrespective of what value you have for value `y` the answer remains the same because while calculating it takes into consideration only `x` value.

```
mean(x = filter(mtcars, am == 1 )$mpg)
#[1] 24.39231
```

What you probably were trying to do was (take note of `c`)

```
mean(c(x = filter(mtcars, am == 1 )$mpg, y = filter(mtcars, vs == 1)$mpg))
#[1] 24.47778
```

but are you sure you wanted this because this filters `am` and `vs` separately so there might be some overlap. When you use `group_by` there is no overlap in the calculation.

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(vs, am) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Mean = mean(mpg))

#    vs    am  Mean
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     0  15.0
#2     0     1  19.8
#3     1     0  20.7
#4     1     1  28.4
```

The mean value is 28.4 for 1, 1 combination of `vs` and `am`

which is same when you do

```
mean(x = filter(mtcars, am == 1 & vs == 1)$mpg)
#[1] 28.37143
```

I hope this explains the basic issue and you could use it to solve it for your data.